# Can I use Stihl fs250 engine for ultralight aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-systems, aircraft-physics, ultralight, plane-construction

RPM 9000
Hp 2.2
Engine weight 6kg
Plane weight 40kg
Body weight. 70
Propellers(2blades) length 30 inches
Wings length 120 inches[image: sthil fs250]

Comment: Highly related (if not a dupe as answers on this question might answer yours): [Can an ultralight aircraft fly with a 18hp engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45160/3394)

Comment: A 2HP engine for an ***ultralight***? Is this serious? Do you mean a drone?

Comment: The Lazair had two engines or 9.5 hp originally, and that was marginal.  You generally want 25 hp or better to have decent climb performance carrying an adult human.